# Change color mode of document from indexed to rgb

Tags: python, automation, photoshop-cs4

I try to convert images from gif to png using photoshop automation.

To be able to save as png I have to convert the image to RGB first.

It should be done using

```
doc.changeMode( ChangeMode.RGB )
```

This gets the error "Invalid argument...required parameter missing"

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, u'Adobe
>   Photoshop', u'Ung\xfcltiges Argument - Argument 1\n- Erforderlicher
>   Wert fehlt', None, 0,

I tried to use the hardcoded value "2" for RGB but get the same result

> doc.changeMode( 2)

How can I convert to RGB?

Here is the complete script:

```
import win32com.client
import xlrd 
import sys, os
import pdb
import os.path

psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")  



# the source File
sourceFile =  "D:\Projekte\myfile.gif"

psApp.Open(   sourceFile ) 
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument

doc.changeMode( 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/photoshop/ChangeMode.html) and the error indicate you are missing a parameter.
Although it looks like `HostObject` is an optional parameter, I don't think you can just leave it out.

```
ChangeMode(ho:HostObject = null, enum:Number)
```

So maybe you shoud try:

```
doc.changeMode(None, 2)
```

(I don't have Photoshop, so I could not try it).

Comment: There is a method called changeMode of the DocumentObject (http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs4_javascript_ref.pdf page 92) and a static property ChangeMode. I use the method of the document and it has 2 arguments: destinationMode and optional parameter object. So this should be ok. I tried the suggested code, but get the same error.

Comment: Well that changeMode has different parameter passings, so you should use 2 as the first parameter. I am not sure what it exactly wants as the second parameter (the conversion options) but I would start out with trying `None` then `[]`. It should be able to use the color lookup table from the `GIF`, but maybe you have to explicitly provide that.

Comment: The options are only needed to convert to Bitmap or indexed mode.